# Oracle Solaris Studio Performance Analyzer 12.3 usage

Tags: java, performance, oracle, profiling, profiler

I have a java program that runs on linux with some lock condition. i want to use Oracle Solaris Studio Performance Analyzer 12.3 to diagnose it.

Using `collect -j on $JAVA $JAVA_OPTS $@` to collect profile data on target machine. And Analyzer(GUI) to view the collected data, but could't find `User Lock` option in Metrics tab like this:

Oops couldn't upload image

which is expected like this:

Oops couldn't upload image

With `er_print` to see the data

> (er_print) metrics e%lock 
>   Error: No data recorded to support metric specification: e%lock 
>   
>   Current metrics: e.user:i.user:name 
>   Current Sort Metric: Exclusive User CPU Time ( e.user ) 
>   Available metrics: 
>   Exclusive User CPU Time: e.%user  
>   Inclusive User CPU Time: i.%user  
>                      Size: size
>                PC Address: address 
>                      Name: name

Also without lock metric in available metrics with non-gui way. 
Is there something wrong with collecting profile data ?  How can i see the `User Lock` option.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2):

To enable **lock profiling** in the Performance Analyzer, you need run the `collect` profile with the `-s on` switch. This will turn on the lock profiling.